# Why is my Java Server Faces HTML dataTable not populating?

Tags: jsf

I'm following the instructions from a book to create a JSF web page.  An init() method that creates an array list.  This list populates the data table, but nothing shows up on the webpage.  I put a logging message in the init method, and no message shows.

EDIT:
Java 1.8.0_222, Payara 5.193.1, NetBeans 8.2

javaee-web-api-8.0, javax.faces-2.2.7, javaee-endorsed-api-7.0

**index.html**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE xhtml PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" [<!ENTITY copy "&#169;">]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Books</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="books.css"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <h1>Michael's book list</h1>
            </header>
            <main>
                <h1>Edit categories</h1>
                <h:form>
                    <h:dataTable value="#{categoryEditor.categories}"
                                 var="cat">
                        <h:column>
                            <h:commandLink
                                action="#{categoryEditor.deleteCategory(cat)}">
                                <h:graphicImage alt="delete"
                                                name="Delete.png"
                                                library="icon/small"
                                                title="delete"/>
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <h:inputText value="#{cat.name}"/>
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>
                    <h:commandLink styleClass="button"
                                   value="Add category"
                                   action="#{categoryEditor.addCategory}"/>
                    <h:commandButton styleClass="button"
                                     value="Save"
                                     action="#{categoryEditor.save}"/>
                </h:form>
            </main>
            <nav>
                This is the Navigation
            </nav>
            <footer>
                &copy; Michael Muller <!-- &copy refers to the copyright sign 
                HTML5 doesn't know such entities, so doctype must be enhanced-->

                <h:outputLink value="http://blog.mueller-bruehl.de">
                    Michael's Blog
                </h:outputLink>

                <h:link value="About" outcome="index.xhtml"/>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**CategoryEditor.java**

```
package us.potato.books;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class CategoryEditor implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger("CategoryEditor");

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        _categories = new ArrayList<>();
        _categories.add(new Category(){{setId(1); setName("Java");}});
        _categories.add(new Category(){{setId(2); setName("Web");}});
        _logger.log(Level.INFO, "Categories initialized");
    }

    private List<Category> _categories;

    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return _categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        _categories = categories;
    }

    public String addCategory(){
        _categories.add(new Category());
        return "";
    }

    public String deleteCategory(Category category){
        _categories.remove(category);
        return "";
    }

    public String save(){
        String categories = "";
        for (Category category : _categories){
            if(!category.getName().isEmpty()){
                if (categories.length() > 0){
                    categories += ", ";
                }
                categories += category;
            }
        }
        _logger.log(Level.INFO, "Save categories: {0}", categories);
        return "";
    }
}
```

**Category.java**

```
package us.potato.books;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class CategoryEditor implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger("CategoryEditor");

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        _categories = new ArrayList<>();
        _categories.add(new Category(){{setId(1); setName("Java");}});
        _categories.add(new Category(){{setId(2); setName("Web");}});
        _logger.log(Level.INFO, "Categories initialized");
    }

    private List<Category> _categories;

    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return _categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        _categories = categories;
    }

    public String addCategory(){
        _categories.add(new Category());
        return "";
    }

    public String deleteCategory(Category category){
        _categories.remove(category);
        return "";
    }

    public String save(){
        String categories = "";
        for (Category category : _categories){
            if(!category.getName().isEmpty()){
                if (categories.length() > 0){
                    categories += ", ";
                }
                categories += category;
            }
        }
        _logger.log(Level.INFO, "Save categories: {0}", categories);
        return "";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>us.potato</groupId>
    <artifactId>Books</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Books</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="4.0" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>\
```

**nb-configuration.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <properties xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/maven-properties-data/1">
        <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion>1.7-web</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion>
        <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>gfv3ee6</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>
        <org-netbeans-modules-projectapi.jsf_2e_language>Facelets</org-netbeans-modules-projectapi.jsf_2e_language>
    </properties>
</project-shared-configuration>
```

Comment: `I put a logging message in the init method, and no message shows` that is the issue and what you included can't answer this. include the configuration

Comment: What's your application server? Do your beans get instantiated at all?

Comment: "Configuration": Do you mean the file structure? Updated

Comment: Payara is a normal Java EE server. Payara is not a servletcontainer like Tomcat. Normal Java EE servers already ship with among others JSF out the box. But yet you're manually providing one along the deployment. This will conflict with the JSF library provided by Payara. Please get rid of the org.glassfish:javax.faces entry in the pom.xml and just rely on the one provided by the target Java EE server and then retry. As far as I know Payara 5.193.1 has Mojarra 2.3.x bundled.

Comment: Removed the faces line from pom.xml: did not fix the table problem; also did not break the page